# Nunit .net vs mono

Tags: c#, mono, nunit

I have written a simple test application using asp.net mvc with C#. The application uses MySQL
by using dblinq to generate linq to MySQL files and the application is working both in windows and linux.

I have now started to use NUnit to test my code, mostly since I need to test if the code working under
windows also will work in linux.
My NUnit tests runs well under Windows but not under Linux.

This my Windows environment:

> NUnit version 2.5.1.9189 Copyright (C)
>   2002-2009 Charlie Poole. Copyright (C)
>   2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C.
>   Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
>   All Rights Reserved.
>
> Runtime Environment -    OS Version:
>   Microsoft Windows NT 5.1.2600 Service 
>   CLR Version: 2.0.50727.3053 ( Net
>   2.0.50727.3053 )

This my Linux environment with the error (Library is my application name):

> NUnit version 2.4.8 Copyright (C)
>   2002-2007 Charlie Poole. Copyright (C)
>   2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C.
>   Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov. Copyright
>   (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig. All Rights
>   Reserved.
>
> Runtime Environment -    OS Version:
>   Unix 2.6.24.24   CLR Version:
>   1.1.4322.2032 ( Mono 2.4.2.2 )
>
> ** (/usr/local/lib/mono/1.0/nunit-console.exe:4888):
>   WARNING **: The class
>   System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
>   could not be loaded, used in System,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 File
>   or assembly name Library.Tests,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null, or one of its
>   dependencies, was not found.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Do you have any tips? It seems like I need to include System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged, I have searched
the Internet to see if it is implemented in mono but I can't find any information.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow you've started the 1.1 CLR - note "CLR Version: 1.1.4322.2032 ( Mono 2.4.2.2 )"

I'm not sure how you've done that, but I'm pretty sure that's the problem... How exactly are you running NUnit? I suspect that the problem is you're using a version of NUnit compiled against .NET 1.1, so Mono decides to load its own CLR v1.1. Assuming you're explicitly calling the `mono` binary, try specifying the `--runtime` argument, like this:

```
mono --runtime=2.0.50727 (whatever you previously had here)
```

EDIT: To find out which runtime version you've got, try this Test.cs file:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.Version);
    }
}
```

Then compile and run it:

```
$ gmcs Test.cs
$ mono Test.exe
2.0.50727.1433
```

What version do you get out at the bottom?

Comment: Maybe I have done something wrong since I have compiled the source myself. I can't however run the code as you mention. Before I run it like this: nunit-console Library.Tests.dll
When I try as you said: mono --runtime=2.0.50727 nunit-console Library.Tests.dll
I get this error
WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
Using default runtime: v1.1.4322
Cannot open assembly 'nunit-console': No such file or directory.

Comment: Well the "nunit-console" problem is probably that you mean "nunit-console.exe" but you need to find the runtime version that works... Editing the answer to help.

Comment: This is pretty strange:
$ mono Test.exe
2.0.50727.1433
But if I run
$ mono --runtime=2.0.50727.1433 Test.exe
1.1.4322.2032
or 
$ mono --runtime=2.0.50727 Test.exe
1.1.4322.2032
Regarding nunit I am running nunit-console and not nunit-console.exe I will search to see if I can find the path to nunit-console.exe and try to run that with 
$ mono nunit-console.exe

Comment: I downloaded nunit and run it instead of using the one coming with mono and i works now.
Thank you Jon for helping me out.

Comment: On my environment (Mac OS X Leopard, Mono 2.6.7), I had to use mono --runtime=v2.0.50727 (whatever you previously had here) (note the extra 'v' character)

Answer (score 3):

Most recent Mono distributions come with two different nunits - one is nunit-console (note no .exe suffix needed, since the packaging supplies convenience shell-scripts), and the other one is nunit-console2.  The first is nunit compiled against the CLR 1.1 profile, and the second is nunit compiled against the CLR 2.0 profile.

So, the short version - you needed to use "nunit-console2" instead of "nunit-console" to get the correct nunit version for your tests.

Answer (score 0):

NUnit 2.5.10 is now supported on both windows and linux. I'm using 2.5.10 at work on both platforms without any problems.