# Trying to get debugging output from Mono NUnit tests

Tags: c#, debugging, mono, nunit, xbuild

I have a rather large C# library, originally written for .NET and Windows, which we are now porting to Mono and Linux.  It is thoroughly unit tested with NUnit.  The porting has been fairly simple, but now I need some real debugging features, like error line numbers and breakpoints.

I'm compiling either using VS2010 on Windows 7 or with xbuild on Debian 6.0.2, it really doesn't matter because the binaries are fully compatible.  Running tests with Mono 2.10.2 built from tarball, and NUnit 2.5.10 from Debian experimental.

When I run my project in Visual Studio, debugging works fine after I attach to the nunit process.  So, does anyone know how I can enable fully-featured Mono debugger support with NUnit tests?

P.S. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317343/mono-debug-information-with-exceptions-on-debian), but I'm compiling with xbuild and running with nunit-console, so I can't manually give arguments to either the compiler or the Mono runtime.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I discovered the pdb2mdb utility, but even when I use this, I still can't get line numbers, which leads me to believe that the code isn't being compiled with --debug.  But since I'm using xbuild on a VS .sln file, instead of invoking the compiler directly, how do I use --debug??

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure out how to get line numbers?

Comment: @wallacer Nope.  We've since switched to using a Jenkins plugin to handle basically everything.  It isn't my primary responsibility anymore, but out failure output still has a bunch of "<filename unknown>:0".  Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.  Jon Skeet comes to the rescue, once again:

[Nunit .net vs mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178058/nunit-net-vs-mono)

After converting to mdb, I needed to run nunit-console**.EXE** from inside the mono command, like this:

```
mono --debug /opt/mono-2.10/lib/mono/4.0/nunit-console.exe Test.dll -config=Debug
```

That took way longer than it should have :P